# Nestjs server does not serve socket.io client

Tags: nestjs

I have a split app using `nestjs` on the server and an `Angular` app as the client. Setting up websockets with socket.io seemed pretty easy using the `@nestjs/websockets` module and on the client I used `ngx-socket-io`. I used this [repo](https://github.com/joshuamorony/ionic-nestjs-websockets-live-chat) as basis. Now when I update the project's `@nestjs/websockets` dependency to the latest version I get

- CORS errors and
- an error that the client couldn't load the socket.io client js file
  [image: http://localhost:3000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mg48H4P]

I expected CORS problems and after the update, I could fix them by adding

```js
  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
    credentials: true,
  });
```

to my `main.ts` file, but I don't know why the client file is not served. With the version of the repo (5.7.x) there are neither CORS errors nor problems with serving the file.

I tried a couple of settings of `@WebSocketGateway()`, moving to a different port, setting `serveClient` (even though it should be `true` by default), but nothing seemed to work. Any advice?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `nestjs` did separate the lower level platform (`socket.io`, `express`, `fastify`, ...) from the `nestjs` modules. The websocket module requires to install an underlying platform, for socket.io

`npm install --save @nestjs/platform-socket.io`

To serve the `socket.io` client file it seems like there also needs to be an HTTP platform installed, for express

`npm install --save @nestjs/platform-express`

More info in the [migration guide](https://docs.nestjs.com/migration-guide#platforms) for v6.

Answer (score 4):

In my case
I replaced

```js
app.useWebSocketAdapter(new WsAdapter(app));
```

from

```js
import { WsAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-ws';
```

with

```js
app.useWebSocketAdapter(new IoAdapter(app));
```

in main `.ts` from

```js
import { IoAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-socket.io';
```

Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. i was opening the client side of the application in the web-browser, but directly from my filesystem (i would double click on the file index.html next to the little dummy fake-front-end.js on my desktop for example...). It seems that the CORS problem would persist until i actually accessed the index.html through a proper server. So i created a route on my backend, to serve the index.html, and the fake-front-end.js.

There is a section about CORS  on the socket.io officual documentation. And there is a section on the nestjs website, but both didnt really helped in my case.